# Error while running (npm install -g @angular/cli) in mac

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to install angular/cli and when I run 
    npm install -g @angular/cli
in the terminal I come up with these error messages, furthermore, I tried to use sudo as a prefix but again not a positive result.

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2018-10-06T04_44_40_632Z- debug.log
```

Comment: Are you sure you're installing the Angular CLI correctly? It looks like npm is trying to read from a repository that has since been renamed to `angular-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

### npm packages should be installed without sudo in macos

> Infact sudo should be never be used unless tinkering with system wide
> permissions. Node puts npm packages in a specific folder, usually
> `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. But the trouble is you need sudo
> permissions to write here. This leads to an endless use of
> non-requisite sudo permissions. This location is what we need to
> change and here are handy terminal commands to achieve the same:

```
mkdir ~/.npm
npm config set prefix ~/.npm
nano ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm/bin"
source ~/.bashrc
```

Quoted from here: https://medium.com/@Mandysidana/using-npm-install-without-sudo-2de6f8a9e1a3

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer
Here is the code just run in terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: NEVER use `sudo npm install`, **in particular on MacOS**